# Connect to website via mobile device

Tags: apache, mobile, wamp, router

I have create a website in php that runs on apache. 

I have copied over the project folder to the www folder in WAMP and created an alias for it.
I have an active wifi connection but want to host the site from my laptop to be accessed on mobile devices. So I created a hotspot using the following command in Admin CMD:

*netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=NetworkName key=NetPassword

netsh wlan start hostednetwork*

This creates a Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter. In adapter settings, I went to properties on my Wifi connection and allowed the created hotspot to have internet access.

My phone is now connected to the created network, however, when I try to access the website, Chrome on my device says that the web page is not available.

I used *mypcname:8080/alias/* to connect to the website.

What could I be doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I think this belong to [superuser](http://superuser.com) or [serverfault](https://serverfault) if it's a professional project.

Comment: I don't think you will get reply here. I think you should post it on serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding http:// to the front, as your webserver is not on the http default port you need to tell the browser what protocol to use